# How to prevent loops in jointjs / rappid

Tags: jointjs

I'm building an application which uses jointjs / rappid and I want to be able to avoid loops from occuring across multiple cells.

Jointjs already has some examples on how to avoid this in a single cell (connecting an "out" port to an "in" port of the same cell) but has nothing on how to detect and prevent loops from occuring further up in the chain.

To help understand, imagine each cell in the paper is a step to be completed. Each step should only ever be run once. If the last step has an "out" port that connects to the "in" port of the first cell, it will just loop forever. This is what I want to avoid.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution through graphlib

Based on [Adam's graphlib solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49171372/6225838), instead of [`findCycles`](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki/API-Reference#alg-find-cycles) to test for loops, the graphlib docs suggests to use the [`isAcyclic` function](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki/API-Reference#alg-is-acyclic), which:

> returns `true` if the graph has no cycles and returns `false` if it does. This algorithm **returns as soon as it detects the first cycle**.

Therefore this condition:

```
if(graphlib.alg.findCycles(graph.toGraphLib()).length > 0)
```

Can be shortened to:

```
if(!graphlib.alg.isAcyclic(graph))
```

## JointJS functions solution

Look up the arrays of [ancestors](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getPredecessors) and [successor](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSuccessors)s of a newly connected element and [intersect](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) them:

```
// invoke inside an event which tests if a specific `connectedElement` is part of a loop

function isElementPartOfLoop (graph, connectedElement) {
  var elemSuccessors = graph.getSuccessors(connectedElement, {deep: true});

  var elemAncestors = connectedElement.getAncestors();
  //       *** OR *** graph.getPredecessors(connectedElement, {deep: true});

  var commonElements = _.intersection(elemSuccessors, elemAncestors);

  // if an element is repeated (non-empty intersection), then it's part of a loop
  return !_.isEmpty(commonElements);
}
```

I haven't tested this, but the theory behind the test you are trying to accomplish should be similar.
This solution is not as efficient as using directly the graphlib functions.

### Prevention

One way you could prevent the link from being added to the graph is by dealing with it in an event:

```
graph.on('add', _.bind(addCellOps, graph));

function addCellOps (cell, collection, opt) {
  if (cell.isLink()){
    // test link's target element: if it is part of a loop, remove the link
    var linkTarget = cell.getTargetElement();
    // `this` is the graph
    if(target && isElementPartOfLoop(this, linkTarget)){
      cell.remove();
    }
  }
  // other operations ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a really easy way to do this for anyone else who wishes to achieve the same thing. Simply include the graphlib dependancy and use the following:

```
        paper.on("link:connect", function(linkView) {
            if(graphlib.alg.findCycles(graph.toGraphLib()).length > 0) {
                linkView.model.remove();
                // show some error message here
            }
        });
```

This line:

```
graphlib.alg.findCycles(graph.toGraphLib())
```

Returns an array that contains any loops, so by checking the length we can determine whether or not the paper contains any loops and if so, remove the link that the user is trying to create.

**Note:** This isn't completely full-proof because if the paper already contains a loop (before the user adds a link) then simply removing the link that the user is creating won't remove any loop that exists. For me this is fine because all of my papers will be created from scratch so as long as this logic is always in place, no loops can ever be created.

Comment: Very nice approach and it's likely to perform better compared to the JointJS default functions. Just leaving the docs link to the [findCycles function](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki/API-Reference#alg-find-cycles).

Comment: Btw, `findCycles` may be useful to detect if the new link's target node/element is actually in the returned array (solving the issue of having a preloaded graph with cycles). For the simple detection of cycles, [`isAcyclic`](https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki/API-Reference#alg-is-acyclic) performs better, so you might want to [replace that condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148580/6225838).